# Socket.io client within an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I am using Node.js, with Socket.IO for communications to the client on my server...

For example:

On my server, I have a `User` class, which contains basic information and functions about each user. Each time someone connects, a new `User` object will be created and added to a `users` array, with the Socket.IO `client` object parsed to it. Here is the code:

```
// Set up server, Socket.IO, etc.

users = [];

var User = function(client) {
    this.value = "some random value";
    this.client = client;
    this.client.on("event",function(data) {
        // Do stuff with data
    });
}

socket.on("connection", function(client) {
    users.push(new User(client));
});
```

My problem is this: when receiving messages with Socket.IO `.on()`, I want to do stuff the `User` object which `client` is owned by. But the problem is that accessing `this` doesn't access the `User` object, but rather the `client` object (or at least I think so, but it isn't the `User` but rather some Socket.IO object). Even when I refer the `.on()` function to call a function in my object, like `this.event` in my `User` object, I still can't access my `User` object with `this`. I tried creating a local variable within each object called `self`, and setting it to `this`, like this: `self = this;`, but I can't edit `this`, but only `self`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
this.client.on("event",function(data) {
  console.log(this.value === "some random value"); // true 
}.bind(this));
```

[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) makes `this` keyword set to the provided value i.e. User object.